# Carbon CreateFromFormat with a localized format

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm trying to convert my localized date with `strftime()` to a Carbon object on Laravel.

Here is my code :

```
$format = Session::get(SESSION_DATE_FORMAT_LOCALIZED);
$dateTime = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $date);
```

```
$format -> "D M j, Y"
$date -> "Ven Décembre 31, 2021"
```

But it says a textual month could not be found. I tried to use the format with "%" but I get the same error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Carbon::setLocale('xx');

Comment: Not working too ..

Comment: Did you try with valid date format $date = '2021-12-31'

Comment: Please read the dedicated chapter of the Carbon documentation https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

Comment: M is not textual month, it's numeric month, F is the correct code for textual month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
echo Carbon::createFromLocaleFormat('D F j, Y', 'fr', 'Ven. Décembre 31, 2021');
```

Short day name/short month names need to match exactly, for instance in French, it's `"Ven."` not `"Ven"` for a `D` format.